# MUI Autocomplete change selected option when another field changes

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik

I have two fields with MUI and Formik, a normal TextField and Autocomplete field. I need select an option on Autocomplete when TextField changes, how do this?

In formik it's all ok, the values sent correct data, but autocomplete do not change to correct value.

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-river-f32btt?file=/src/demo.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options property is an array but the value is represented by a string. You need to pass a function to the `isOptionEqualToValue` property that the `AutoComplete` component will use to figure out which item in the array of items matches the current value.

You also need to move the `value` property out of the text field and pass it directly to the autocomplete so that it can manage its own value.

```js
<Autocomplete
  filterSelectedOptions
  id="estado"
  name="estado"
  options={states}
  clearText="Apagar"

  // Add the following props
  isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.value === value}
  value={formik.values.estado}

  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      error={Boolean(formik.errors.estado)}
      helperText={formik.errors.estado}
    />
  )}
  onChange={(e, newValue) => {
    formik.handleChange({
      target: { name: "estado", value: newValue.value },
    });
  }}
/>;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @abirtaheer, I hadn't understood the `isOptionEqualToValue` property, your code works perfectly

Comment: Hi, I hope you can help me. My getOptionLabel its a bit overworked as it needs to show the company and the contact name, unless the company has no employees. 
It looks like this: 
`getOptionLabel={jsonResults => jsonResults?.nombre_contacto ?
              jsonResults?.nombre_empresa +": "+jsonResults?.nombre_contacto +" "+ jsonResults?.apellidos_contacto
              : jsonResults?.nombre_empresa`
So, what should I do in this case inside `isOptionEqualToValue` ? Please take your time to lend me a hand, I really need some help @abirTaheer.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably arrange this better, but this works

```
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);
  
  function onBlurCep(ev, setFieldValue) {
    let selected = states.find((v) => v.label === formik.values.cep) || {};
    setSelected(selected);

  - - - -

  <Autocomplete
      value={selected}
```

Comment: Thanks @Dylan, the Abir answer fixed this problem!